# Redirecting unlogged user from Checkout to My Account

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

I am trying to redirect logged-out users to the "my account" page when they try to checkout.

I have tried this but it's not working as expected:

```
function wpse_131562_redirect() {
    if (
        ! is_user_logged_in()
        && (is_cart() || is_checkout())
    ) {
       
        wp_redirect('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id'());
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'wpse_131562_redirect');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can't work as there is no redirect link… Try the following instead *(redirecting unlogged user from Checkout to My Account)*:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'unlogged_my_account_redirect');
function unlogged_my_account_redirect() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) {
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') ) );
        exit();
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.